# Very big string trie in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, trie

I need to load a few millions of short (length < 16) strings into a string trie in Haskell from the file and then to perform many very fast look-ups. What is the best way how to do that in Haskell? Would appreciate any strategy (package).

*Note*: It must be a trie, because I need the search logic of a trie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[bytestring-trie](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring-trie/0.1.4/doc/html/Data-Trie.html#t%3aKeyString). I think it is fast enough for most of the purposes.